# Why did my oven light stop working after cleaning the oven?

Tags: appliances, oven, troubleshooting

I replaced the bulb in the oven with a new bulb and it won't light. Both the old bulb & new bulb work in a table lamp.  The light stopped working after cleaning the oven. Any suggestions?  Is there fuse some where?

Comment: Is it a self-cleaning oven? What's the oven's model number?  You can use that to look up the manual on the internet, and that will tell you if there's a fuse that you can replace.

Comment: Or a lightbulb that you can replace.

Comment: I have the owners manual & installtion manual from the previous homeowner.  Neither manual has schematic diagrams to indicate where a fuse may be. It is a self cleaning oven. Model # JGBP24GEN Serial # TD 20296 HP.  The button switch that the door activates to turn on the light still moves in & out I checked that to make sure it was not stuck in.  I followed the manuals procedure for changing the bulb.

Answer (score 2):

The self cleaning cycle heats the oven up to 900-1000°F so if it worked before it may be that some damage was caused during the cycle either to the socket or to the switch.  Try putting a multimeter on the socket to see if you have power, then click the switch and test again.  If there is no power during either test then it is probably the switch.